# textfield conditional set a text in a label

Tags: php, html, conditional-statements

I have a doubt in php
If I have a textfield

```
<input name="testnumber" type="text" size="5" maxlength="3" />
```

And the user types a thing (number) ; I need something to appear according to the numerical quantity established in a label; Example: The user types between 1.0 and 3.0 on the label "improve" , if the user types between 3.1 and 4.0 " OK " ;

```
<?php
$flower = "rose";

switch ($flower)
{
  case "rose" : 
     echo $flower." costs $2.50";
     break;
  case "daisy" : 
     echo $flower." costs $1.25";
     break;
  case "orchild" : 
     echo $flower." costs $1.50";
     break;
  default : 
     echo "There is no such flower in our shop";
     break;
}
?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Prueba condicionales</title>
</head>

<body>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Datos recuperados</legend>

        <div>
            <?php include ("conexion_consulta.php"); $conn = new conexion(); $conn-> recuperardatos(); ?>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <form action="" method="post" name="prueba condicional">
        <label>Nota</label> <input maxlength="3" name="notadeprueba" size="5"
        type="text"><br>
        <label>Desempeño</label>
        <hr>
        <input name="send" type="button" value="Send_db">
    </form>if(){ }
</body>
</html>
```

I need to do without "echo " label is what I need because many data.

Thank you very much .

Comment: It would help if you could share your code, I do not understand the question

Comment: <html>
<head>
<title>Prueba condicionales</title>
</head>

<body>
<fieldset>
<legend> Datos recuperados</legend>
<div>
<?php
include ("conexion_consulta.php");
$conn = new conexion();
$conn-> recuperardatos();
?>
</div>
</fieldset>
<form action="" method="post" name="prueba condicional">
<label>Nota</label>
<input name="notadeprueba" type="text" size="5" maxlength="3" />
<br />
<label>Desempeño</label>
<hr>
<input name="send" type="button" value="Send_db">
</form>

if(){
}

</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 validation (simplest method) :

```
<input maxlength="3" name="notadeprueba" size="5"
    type="number" min="1" max="3">
```

http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/

If that really doesn't fit your needs then use a Javascript Validation to set label according to what is inside the textfield

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_form_validations.htm